# Css div border going around everything not just its contents

Tags: html, css, border

I have an issue with the `border-radius` of `div container2` for the links list with the resolutions at the top of the page like 240x320 etc. Its going around everything instead of just left-column2 and right-column2. Container2 is used a second time in the code without issue so i don't understand it.

At first i thought it was a problem with a closing tag but checked the code and everything is fine.

Heres my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nRmc9/6/). Hopefully someone knows whats going on with it.

Comment: Additionally, you have at least five open <li>s that aren't closed. Technically this is allowed in HTML5 as long as they are followed by another <li> or a </ul>, but are you sure you don't have any closing tag problems?

Comment: Not with the divs. I may have over highlighted and deleted some of the ul when simplifying the code for easier reading.

Comment: Well for starters you have divs that aren't closed properly, that'll cause things to mess up (look at line 21 on your fiddle). You're also ending and starting divs in very weird places, looks to me as if they're overlapping, that will also cause things to mess up. You need to go over your code again and put everything in a logical order.

Comment: I have mistaken that div for a closed div. Embarrassing but it does happen i guess. Thanks for pointing that out, it solved my issue :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it has to do with the box-model . `width` + `padding`.

To include `padding` into `width` and use `width:100%` on child , you can switch the box model with `box-sizing`: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nRmc9/12/)**

```
.container1,
.container2 {
box-sizing:border-box;/* add prefixed rules if needed */
}
```

SEE: **[W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing0)**

Comment: I already have this in my css * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;

Comment: @Techagesite it is not in your fiddle linked, no way for anyone to guess :)

Comment: Yeah i will start including it :)

Answer (score 0):

It was pointed out that i had mistaken an open div for a closed div. Thats why i was having issues with the border.